# How to replace null value with some value using coalesce in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, pyspark-schema

I have two files :- orders_renamed.csv , customers.csv
I am joining them with full outer join and then dropping same column (customer_id).
I want to replace null vaue to "-1" in "order_id" column.

I have tried this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, monotonically_increasing_id, unix_timestamp, from_unixtime, coalesce from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructField, StructType, StringType

ordersDf = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).option("path", "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/week12/week 12 dataset/orders_renamed.csv").load()

customersDf = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).option("path", "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/week12/week 12 dataset/customers.csv").load()

joinCondition1 = ordersDf.customer_id == customersDf.customer_id

joinType1 = "outer"   


joinenullreplace = ordersDf.join(customersDf, joinCondition1, joinType1).drop(ordersDf.customer_id).select("order_id", "customer_id", "customer_fname").sort("order_id").withColumn("order_id",coalesce("order_id",-1))


joinenullreplace.show(50)
```

as in last line i have used coalesce but it is giving me error..i have tried multiple ways like treting coalesce as one expression and applying 'expr'
but it did not work.
I have also used lit but it did not work.
please reply solution.

Comment: if the `order_id` column is of string type, you'll need to pass a string column or literal in `coalesce`. if it's a literal, enclose the value in `lit()`.

Comment: I have used lit but it is also giving me error . 

.withColumn("order_id",coalesce("order_id",lit(1)))                       

what import i have to use for this lit?

Comment: it is a [pyspark function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html). same import as `col()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
```

Comment: it'd be good to explain why and how your single line would help OP.